# how does this unique if statement work in Java?

Tags: java

The result of this if statement was asked in my final exam. Afterwards, I searched for this sort of If statement but couldn't find it. Here's an example of this if statement. I experimented with it and apparently it works in mysterious ways :D

```
int a=1, b=1;
if(a != b >> 1)
{
    System.out.println("ABC");
}
```

Comment: It's comparing `a` and `(b >> 1)` (bitshift right once), which is the same as `b / 2`. And since `b` is an `int` (and `1`), that is `0`. So, `if 1 != 0`... thus it will print `ABC`.

Comment: Right shift operator

Comment: The operations (>>) will be first later (!=). Here you can read more about the priority of the logic operations: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/  and here: https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/operator-precedence